# Efficient way to use forEachPartition in Apache Spark in Java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have dataset with one column (let say: empId) which can have large number of rows(18k-20k or more) and
I am trying to use

```
Dataset<Row> allEmpIds=inputData;
    allEmpIds.repartition(100).foreachPartition(rootPartition -> {
        if (!rootPartition.hasNext()) {
            return;
        }
        rootPartition.forEachRemaining(row -> {
        ....code to generate report for each empIds
       });
```

But this is throwing error

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

```
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:416)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:406)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:163)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2332)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$1(RDD.scala:979)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:385)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:978)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$foreachPartition$1(Dataset.scala:2741)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withNewRDDExecutionId$1(Dataset.scala:3354)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewRDDExecutionId(Dataset.scala:3350)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.foreachPartition(Dataset.scala:2741)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.foreachPartition(Dataset.scala:2752)
```

I am using repartition to run spark job in parallel for faster computation as for each empId I have to some computations which is time consuming.
Can someone help here?

Thanks

Comment: I recommend you read about serialization in Spark and why it's an important aspect.

Comment: Then, to actually help you we will need more details like the complete stack trace and the actual code. With what you've shown, there's no chance we can help you.

Comment: I have added complete stacktrace. Can you check now?

Comment: I think you are trying to access some non serializable object in your forEachPartition block. This can be your code or any dependency function that you are calling. You need to figure that out. Also like @GaëlJ mentioned, read about serialization in Spark.

Comment: Down the stack trace, somewhere you should have more clue as to which class is not serializable.